# Get text after button clicked android

Tags: java, android

I have a result statement that execute two queries.
the first query gets text from an edit text but not after button clicked.
the second one gets some stuff from the table in the database.
how can i make an onClickListener to my button so that it gets the text,
after the button gets clicked **ONLY** the query gets executed not all
the class(which contains my query)

here is my code (which executes the whole class for now)

```
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        connectionClass = new ConnectionClass();
        itemArrayList = new ArrayList<ClassListChat>();
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.chatlist);
        themsg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourmsg);
        send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);


send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try{
            String editTextData = themsg.getText().toString();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("ActivityName", "Exception caused by editText " + e.toString());
        }
        new SyncData(editTextData).execute();
    }

});

    }



    private class SyncData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        String msg;
        ProgressDialog progress;
        String editTextData;


        public void SyncData(String editTextData) {
            this.editTextData = editTextData;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() //Starts the progress dailog
        {
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(ChatActivity.this, "Loading...",
                    "Please Wait...", true);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings)  // Connect to the database, write query and add items to array list
        {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {


                    try {
                        Connection conn = connectionClass.CONN(); //Connection Object
                        if (conn == null) {
                            success = false;
                            msg = "Sorry something went wrong,Please check your internet connection";
                        } else {
                            // Change below query according to your own database.
                            Date c = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
                            String formattedDate = df.format(c);
                            System.out.println("it isssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"+formattedDate);


                            String query = "Insert into CustomerSupportChat values('" + formattedDate + "','" + editTextData + "','Customer','3','"+getIntent().getStringExtra("nameid")+"','1','1') " +
                                    "Select MessageID,MessageDate,MessageText,SenderType,MessageRecieved,MessageReaded,Users_Login_Data.Username,StoresData.StoreEnglishName,StoresData.StoreArabicName FROM " +
                                    "CustomerSupportChat INNER JOIN Users_Login_Data ON " +
                                    "CustomerSupportChat.CustomerID = Users_Login_Data.CustomerID INNER JOIN StoresData ON " +
                                    "CustomerSupportChat.StoreID = StoresData.StoreID Where SenderType = 'Customer'";
                            String query2 =
                                    "Select MessageID,MessageDate,MessageText,SenderType,MessageRecieved,MessageReaded,Users_Login_Data.Username,StoresData.StoreEnglishName,StoresData.StoreArabicName FROM " +
                                    "CustomerSupportChat INNER JOIN Users_Login_Data ON " +
                                    "CustomerSupportChat.CustomerID = Users_Login_Data.CustomerID INNER JOIN StoresData ON " +
                                    "CustomerSupportChat.StoreID = StoresData.StoreID Where SenderType = 'Store'";

                            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                            Statement stmt2 = conn.createStatement();

                            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                            ResultSet rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery(query2);


                            if (rs != null && rs2!= null) // if resultset not null, I add items to itemArraylist using class created
                            {
                                while (rs.next() && rs2.next()) {

                                    try {
                                        itemArrayList.add(new ClassListChat(rs.getString("MessageDate"),rs.getString("MessageText") ,rs.getString("SenderType"),rs2.getString("MessageText")));
                                        System.out.println("THEY AREEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE "+rs.getString("MessageDate")+ " " +rs.getString("MessageText")+ " " + rs.getString("SenderType")+ " " + rs2.getString("MessageText"));
                                        themsg.setText("");
                                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                                        ex.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }

                                msg = "Found";
                                success = true;
                            } else {
                                msg = "No Data found!";
                                success = false;
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Writer writer = new StringWriter();
                        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(writer));
                        msg = writer.toString();
                        Log.d("Error", writer.toString());
                        success = false;
                    }

                }
            });
            return msg;
        }
```

the edit text i want to get text from is `themsg`.

**EDIT:** I have updated my code but now it shows me an error on the second editTextData in the OnClickListener.

Comment: You are using a local editTextData which is not accessible outside the try block. So it will throw you an error. You can instead have String editTextData = ""; as the first line in the onClickListener and then in the try block just assign the editTextData the value from the editText

Comment: Okay thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you are doing it right:

```
send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
      try{
        String editTextData = themsg.getText().toString();
      }
      catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("ActivityName", "Exception caused by editText " + e.toString());
      }
      new SyncData(editTextData).execute();
  }
});
```

Also change the SyncData function's definition to accept this editText value by making a field property and initializing it through SyncData's constructor.

```
private class SyncData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    String msg;
    ProgressDialog progress;
    Strind editTextData;

    public void SyncData(String editTextData) {
      this.editTextData = editTextData;
    }
```

this way you can pass whatever value the editText hold at the moment the button is clicked and pass it to your AsyncTask.

Comment: Thank you ,but whenever i add your code to the onclicklistener it gives me an error on the second editTextData.

Comment: Sorry am not used to classes,could you add an example please!

Comment: Edited the answer. Please refer.

Comment: by query if you mean onClickListener like i did then yes. If you copy the code to the places that I edited, then that should do the job.

Comment: Okay, i have done like you advised me exactly but it still shows me the same error.

Comment: Could you please help?

Comment: update the lod result to show the new error. Always keep your post updated. Put nex code and remove old one.

Comment: But there is no new error,just the same error as before which is the onclicklistener shows me an error on the second editTextData

Comment: Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

This looks correct. You probably need to do some debugging to be sure you are getting the data. You could log it. I will add a log message. Check the log if the message print on click on the button. I also added trim to remove white space. Also, comment on the line where you are calling the SyncData to be sure the problem is not from there.

Meanwhile for your subsequent project you could consider using Room Database architecture and AppExecutor with Java and Coroutines if you are using Kotlin for managing asynchronous task.

```
send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try{
            String editTextData = themsg.getText().toString().trim();
            Log.d("Activityname", editTextData)
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("ActivityName", "Exception caused by editText " + e.toString());
        }
        //new SyncData(editTextData).execute();
    }

});
```